# call R from Stata with rsource - not working

Tags: r, stata

I want to create some random variables in R and return them in Stata, all written in one do file. I used `rsource` with option `terminator()`. This is a short version of my do file (just to mention, R commands are taken from R file that is working, and by calling these diretly in R it does produce X.dta)...

```
clear
set more off

cd "C:\Users\....\Desktop\R_stata"


rsource, terminator(END_OF_R)  rpath(C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\R.exe) 


library(mvtnorm);
library(foreign);


xmean<-rep(0,100);
x1Sigma<- diag(100);
x2Sigma<- 2 * diag(100);

X1<-rmvnorm(n=1, mean=xmean, sigma=x1Sigma);
X1<- t(X1);
X2<-rmvnorm(n=1, mean=xmean, sigma=x2Sigma);
X2<- t(X2);

write.dta(data.frame(X1, X2), "C:/Users/...../Desktop/R_stata/X.dta");


END_OF_R

use X.dta, replace
```

Comment: I'm not a Stata user, but I can say that I have sometimes been tripped up in R by trying to have expressions evaluated as the first argument to write.* functions. I would skip the assignments with `t(.)` and instead create `newfrm <- data.frame(X1, X2)` and then pass to the write.dta function via its name.

Comment: just tried it, but still the same, nothing happens with running the file, and also no error message in stata (except the one when i want to open X.dta that is not created)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to add `roptions("--vanilla")` to your `rsource`. Without that option, I get

```
file X.dta not found
r(601);
```

With it, it works perfectly for me.